# Jenkins security as an open-source tool

Tags: security, jenkins, open-source

I work in a corporate development environment that is fairly risk-averse where management is often afraid of change. I've prototyped out how a Jenkins solution for our development team might work, and highlighted some success stories where the pilot implementation has helped, but the time has now come to get it approved to a wider audience and in a more permanent way, and some security concerns have been raised.

Primarily, the concerns so far have focused on the fact that the tool is open-sourced and the plugins are open-sourced and made by community contributors, so management is concerned that somebody could insert malicious code that would go unnoticed by us when we update. My opinion is that if so many other places can make Jenkins work, we probably can too, but that is not necessarily a very compelling argument to our security testing team.

My question is, can anybody tell me how they have secured their own Jenkins implementations, or how what specific Jenkins capabilities (sandboxing, etc) are in place to prevent malicious code from being executed on our systems?

Answer (score 0):

Using 3rd party components either in your software or your infrastructure will always have risks. One very important thing to note is that open source is not less secure than closed source. While probably anybody might contribute code to an open source project, in most cases there is review before it actually makes its way into the project. Of course, a vulnerability may slip through, but how is that different from a software company with lots of developers? A vulnerability may slip through there too, and based on the experience of many of us, it quite often does. :) And in case of closed source, you don't even have the power of a diverse community to spot such security flaws, the best you can rely on are 3rd party penetration tests or code scans, both of which miss many issues.

In case of such a well established project like Jenkins, you can be pretty sure that there is *lots* of scrutiny on its security, probably more so than any closed source commercial tool you may currently have.

As with any 3rd party component, you should exercise due diligence though. Have a look at online vulnerability databases like [NVD](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search) regularly to find security issues. Install updates as they come out to mitigate the risk. You should do these for closed source components too.

As for how to secure a Jenkins installation, an answer here is not the right format I think, but there is a whole set of pages [on their website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins) dedicated to the topic.

Having said all this and looking at past vulnerabilities in Jenkins, there are quite a few. It's up to you (and your security department) to assess how exactly you would want to deploy Jenkins, and whether those past vulnerabilities are serious enough for you to think the whole tool is not adequate for your environment considering the way you want to deploy it.  Again, it's the same process you would follow with a closed source tool too.